# Transition derivative for Continuous Time Markov Chains notation

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-processes, notation, terminology, self-learning

Having already studied Discrete Time Markov Chains, I have recently began to self-study the the natural extension to Continuous Time Markov Chains. One of the very first concepts to appear is the notion of a Q-Matrix with entries in the form $q_{i,j}$ for the $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix. The textbook that I am using provides the following definition for these entires:

> **Transition Derivatives:** We define $q_{i,j} := \lim _{\delta \downarrow 0} \big{(}\frac{p_\delta (i,j) - p_0 (i,j)}{\delta} \big{)}$ for $i,j \in I$

There are a few things that are unclear to me here.

1. I believe that time-homogeneity is assumed for the Markov Chain and so I'm not sure what the notation $p_{\delta} (i,j)$ and $p_0(i,j)$ refer to. I know that $p_{i,j}(t) = \mathbb{P} (X_t = j : X_0 = i)$, but this notation seems to be written backwards. Is this just a mistake / inconsistency by the author?
2. Assuming that my assumption in point $(1)$ is correct, I am unsure about what this quantity actually represents. It seems to be calculating the change in probability of transitioning state over a small time with respect to time. But my understanding is that changes in state occur instantaneously and so I am not sure I understand how we can interpret the concept of a rate of change in a context where we don't have a gradual transition from one state to another.

I would be grateful for any clarification here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The notation can vary considerably between different authors, but I think it's reasonable in this case to assume that $p_\delta(i,j)$ is the same as $p_{i,j}(\delta)$, that is, the probably you end up in state $j$ at time $\delta$ given you started in state $i$ at time $0$. I have seen both notations used (in the same 1-hour lecture, no less!).
2. One nice interpretation is to think of the $q_{i,j}$s as rate parameters for exponential random variables. If you're in state $i$ at time $t=0$, and you can move from state $i$ to states $j_1,\dots,j_n$, then you can imagine that at each of the states $j_1,\dots,j_n$, there's an alarm clock that will ring at a random, exponentially-distributed time, where the parameters for the exponential random variables are $q_{i,j_1},\dots,q_{i,j_n}$, respectively. When the first "alarm clock" rings, then you move to the state associated with that clock (actually, this construction works for countably infinite state spaces as well).

I am sure many stochastic processes texts will discuss this interpretation/construction of continuous-time Markov chains; one fairly accessible source (that's more heavy on intuition and less heavy on formalism—and is also where I picked up this "alarm clock" analogy) is [Lawler's book](http://www.sze.hu/%7Eharmati/Sztochasztikus%20folyamatok/lawler.pdf).

Comment: One follow up question to part $2$: How do we interpret $q_{i,i}$? I can't quite see how this analogy accounts for this @KenaskiBowspleefi

Comment: @FD_bfa Ah, good point. In the matrix $Q$, $q_{i,i}$ will be $-\sum_j q_{i,j}$. One way of interpreting this is that $\sum_j q_{i,j}$ is the rate parameter for the r.v. defined as the minimum of the exponential “alarm clock” variables (if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent exponential r.v.s with rates $a_1,\dots,a_n$, the r.v. $Y=\min\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ is exponential with rate $\sum_i a_i$). So $q_{i,i}$ represents the total rate at which the chain leaves state $i$ (and is negative, to represent “leaving,” and so that $Q$ behaves properly).